# How and why did the strange family from "The Enchanted" (1984) turn into humans?

Tags: the-enchanted

I watched the film **[The Enchanted](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1323573/)** last night randomly and unless I misunderstood something in the film, how and more importantly *why* did the strange family that lives in the woods turn into humans?

It only shows them at the end turning back into their original form but I don't understand why they chose to change into human form in the first place.

What was the purpose for their actions?

Comment: Never saw the movie, but I have the book somewhere in my basement.  Loved it when I was younger!

Comment: @HTG - Any insights from the book?

Comment: @HTG: And can you say who the author is? I don't see anything on the IMDB page saying what it's adapted from.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The Enchanted
by Elizabeth Coatsworth https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2097296.The_Enchanted

Comment: I think they just wanted some kid of protection - not to be killed by hunters. Better to read the book though )