# What book, if any, is the 1984 film "The Enchanted" based on?

Tags: the-enchanted

I ran into ["The Enchanted" 1984 - confused by the plot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52629/the-enchanted-1984-confused-by-the-plot?rq=1) as a "related question" and I find myself intrigued by a secondary mystery. User HTG (not around since some time last year) [mentions in the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52629/the-enchanted-1984-confused-by-the-plot?rq=1#comment153630_52629) that they "have the book".

> Never saw the movie, but I have the book somewhere in my basement. Loved it when I was younger! – HTG Nov 25 '14 at 3:09

However, I've found no indication of the film being based on a book on the IMDb page. I've done some ISFDb searches for books named *The Enchanted*, or starting with that title, and written at or before 1984, but have had no luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [movie site](https://www.theenchantedthemovie.com/) states:

> **Facts About The Enchanted**
>
> Based on a novel written by the well known children's author Elizabeth
>   Coatsworth, this unusual and internationally successful independent
>   feature film...

Wikipedia's page on [Elizabeth Coatsworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Coatsworth) lists it as part of a series:

> **The Incredible Tales**
>
> - The Enchanted, Pantheon, 1951
> - Silky: An Incredible Tale, Pantheon, 1953
> - Mountain Bride: An Incredible Tale, Pantheon 1954
> - The White Room, Pantheon, 1958

The book is available for sale (some new, but mostly used) at the major online booksellers.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I must have been missing something.